# Project_Change VBA Code (Microsoft Project) Isn't Being Fired

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm new to VBA and am trying to make a macro that generates a userform to allow the user to input a UID number and output the total slack. I also want the total slack output to be updated as changes are manually made in the schedule. My userform currently works except that I can't seem to activate the Project_Change method. In other words, I can type in any UID and get the desired output. However, if I make a change to the slack value in the schedule, the slack value won't show any changes in the userform (or the message box that should print "hi"). Thanks in advance!

Project Module Code:

```
Sub ShowSlack()
    UserForm10.Show False
End Sub

Private Sub Project_Change(ByVal pj As Project)
    MsgBox "hi"
    UserForm10.UpdateTotalSlack
End Sub
```

Userform Module Code:

```
Dim User_UID As Variant
Dim TSlack As Variant

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    User_UID = UserForm10.TextBox3.Value
    UpdateTotalSlack
End Sub

Sub UpdateTotalSlack()
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not User_UID = "" Then
        TSlack = ActiveProject.Tasks.UniqueID(User_UID).TotalSlack / 480
    Else
        TSlack = ""
    End If
    UserForm10.Label1.Caption = TSlack
End Sub
```